# why it is blank applet in java folder

Tags: java

I have two questions:

1.I installed `jdk_7` in system but when I want to use  exist applets, applets folder is blank.

2.I installed `jdk_10` in system but don't have applets folder.

What's the problem?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Applets are dead